# reducing number of php pagination links to 10

Tags: php, html, pagination

Ive been building a data driven website displaying general info about countries in the world. Its been made so that 1 country is displayed per page and you can move the next country by clicking a pagination link. Only problem that I am having is I cannot limit the amount of visible links. I did try this for loop with the first line as this: for ($i = $Page; $i <= min($Page + 9, $TotalRecords); $i++) { which does reduce it to the 10 records however this does result in the website breaking when I test the web address by entering index.php?page=aa.

```
<nav class="mt-5">
   <ul class="pagination pagination-lg justify-content-center">
       <?php
          if( isset($Page) ) {
             if ($Page > 1 ) {
       ?>
       <li class="page-item">
          <a href="index.php?page=<?php echo $Page-1; ?>" class="page-link">&laquo;</a>
       </li>
       <?php 
               } 
           }
       ?>
       <?php
       global $ConnectingDB;
       $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM countriesinfo";
       $stmt = $ConnectingDB->query($sql);
       $RowPagination = $stmt->fetch();
       $TotalRecords = array_shift($RowPagination);
       $RecordPagination = $TotalRecords / 1;
       $RecordPagination = ceil($RecordPagination);
       for ($i = $Page; $i <= $RecordPagination; $i++) {     
            if( isset($Page) ) {
                  if ($i == $Page) 
                          {  
       ?>
       <li class="page-item active">
             <a href="index.php?page=<?php echo $i; ?>" class="page-link"><?php  echo $i; ?></a>
       </li>
       <?php
            } else {
       ?>  
       <li class="page-item">
            <a href="index.php?page=<?php echo $i; ?>" class="page-link"><?php  echo $i; ?></a>
       </li>
       <?php      
                 }
              } 
           } 
       ?>
       <?php if (isset($Page) && !empty($Page) ) {
             if ($Page+1 <= $RecordPagination) {
       ?>
       <li class="page-item">
           <a href="index.php?page=<?php echo $CountryId+1; ?>" class="page-link">&raquo;</a>
       </li>
       <?php 
      } 
     }
   ?>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

### I test the web address by entering index.php?page=aa.

You can check to make sure the get variable is a number by using php is_numeric() bulit in function
and if it isn't force it to number 1.
This will stop the website from breaking when someone manipulate the page varible.

Here is a code to help you out, put at the beginning of the page.

```
  if(is_numeric($page)){
      $page = $page; // if $page is a number do nothing
     }else{
       $page = 1; //else set $page to 1 which  will fetch data from  beginning
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this did fix the problem

Comment: You are welcome, glad it worked out in the end happy coding.